# Formstone Upload - drop file on div is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I need simply and tidy javascript library for upload image with drag&drop option. I found [Formstone](https://formstone.it/components/upload/), but I have some problem with it. According to documentation I have created div:

```
<div class="target" style="border:dotted; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

and just bind this div with formstone script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".target").upload({
        action: "/upload.php"
    });
});
```

Now in my div appear input file - if I choose file by this input is ok (just check whether `$('.fs-upload-input')[0].files[0].name` return filename in console), if I dropped file on this input is ok, but if I dropped file on my div but not on input it's not works - internet browser just display file because Formstone library not catch to file.

I've made [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Loa7ef7/) with sample.

The question is: why formstone not bind my div?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with attempting to load the source files from github, try using CDNJS instead:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formstone/1.1.3/js/core.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formstone/1.1.3/js/upload.js